# Data inputted on separate rows when uploading an image alongside other information in a form. I am using code igniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Data inputted on separate rows when uploading an image alongside other information in a form. I am using code igniter.
The image details entered on their own row and other inputs like name,address  entered on their own rows.

**My Controller**

```
public function addRecordToTable(){


$this->load->model('consignmentupload_model');  
$this->load->library('form_validation');   
$this->form_validation->set_rules('client_id' , 'client_id', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('l_address' , 'l_address', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('l_area' , 'l_area', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('d_area' , 'd_area', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('preferred' , 'preferred', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('dom' , 'dom', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('tom' , 'tom', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description' , 'description', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mass' , 'mass', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
    $array = array(
                    'client_id' => $this->input->post('client_id'),
                    'l_address' => $this->input->post('l_address'),
                    'l_area' => $this->input->post('l_area'),
                    'd_address' => $this->input->post('d_address'),
                    'd_area' => $this->input->post('d_area'),
                    'preferred' => $this->input->post('preferred'),
                    'dom' => $this->input->post('dom'),
                    'tom' => $this->input->post('tom'),
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    //'consignment_picture' => $this->input->post('consignment_picture'),
                    'mass' => $this->input->post('mass'),
    );

    $record_id = $this->consignmentupload_model->addData('consignment', $array);
    $this->uploadFiles($record_id);
}
}


   public function uploadFiles($record_id){

$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => FCPATH . "/uploads/",
    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
    'overwrite'     => TRUE,                       
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$files = $_FILES['uploads'];

foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $filename) {
    $_FILES['uploads[]']['name']     = $files['name'][$key];
    $_FILES['uploads[]']['type']     = $files['type'][$key];
    $_FILES['uploads[]']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$key];
    $_FILES['uploads[]']['error']    = $files['error'][$key];
    $_FILES['uploads[]']['size']     = $files['size'][$key];

    $config['file_name'] = $filename;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (isset($_FILES['uploads[]']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['uploads[]']['name'])) {
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploads[]')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } else {
            $uploads[] = $this->upload->data();
            $array = array(
                'record_id' => $record_id,
                'filename'  => $_FILES['uploads[]']['name'],
                'size'      => $_FILES['uploads[]']['size']
            );
            $this->consignmentupload_model->addData('consignment', $array);
        }
    }
}
redirect(site_url('clientaccount_ctrl'));
 }
```

**My Model**

```
    public function addData($table, $array)
    {
       $this->db->insert($table, $array);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

**My Table structure**

Columns - luggage_id, client_id, l_area, l_address, d_area, preferred, dom, tom, description, mass, record_id, filename, size, upload time, status,
Image folder is uploads and its on the root

Comment: You are using `$this->consignmentupload_model->addData()` twice. so it insert data every time when this function called. you have to use `update` query for upload image in `uploadFiles()` function

Comment: I see the code, but I'm not clear on what the issue is your having. What is the expected behavior and what behavior are you getting instead?

Comment: I  add the form details to a table add the image to a folder. The code can do that but its adding the form details (client_id,l_address etc) and image details(filename,size and record_id) in two separate rows, i want the data to be added on one row.